# R converting datetime format in foreign language not working

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to use the package `parsedate` to parse/convert several different datetime formats into a uniform/homogenous format the issue is that some dates will be in English (my machine language) and some will be in Spanish allow me to illustrate:

I have two vectors:

```
#English dates
dates<-c("2016 jun 15 8:39 p.m","2016 apr 2 8:39 a.m","2016 dec 2 8:39 a.m")
#Spanish dates
fechas<-c("2016 junio 15 8:39 p.m","2016 abril 2 8:39 a.m","2016 diciembre 2 8:39 a.m")
```

I noticed that the function `parse_date()` correctly converts the vector `dates` into the desired output format, but when trying to parse the vector with Spanish dates it does not work even when changing local time to "Spanish" as is shown below:

```
#Parsing english dates
parsedate::parse_date(dates)

> parsedate::parse_date(dates)
[1] "2016-06-15 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-04-02 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-12-02 08:39:00 UTC"


#Parsing spanish dates
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
parsedate::parse_date(fechas)

> Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish")
[1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"
> parsedate::parse_date(fechas)
[1] "2016-01-15 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-01-02 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-01-02 08:39:00 UTC"
```

The Spanish output is wrong because it should return the same output in the English dates, I have tried several ways to properly change the local time of my machine to Spanish with no luck.
I will be very thankful if you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/781

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Spanish_Spain.1252")
format <- "%a@%A@%b@%B@%p@"
enc2utf8(unique(format(lubridate:::.date_template, format = format)))
str(lubridate:::.get_locale_regs("Spanish_Spain.1252"))
```

```
library(lubridate)

Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "Spanish_Spain.1252"

parse_date_time(fechas, 'ymd HM')
```

```
[1] "2016-06-15 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-04-02 08:39:00 UTC" "2016-12-02 08:39:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! may I kindly ask what does ""%a@%A@%b@%B@%p@" do? if I want to go back to english as dates will it affect it? Thank you so much again

Comment: This code is from the referred issue page on github. The issue seems to be that es_ES.utf8 doesn't exist in Windows. This code is a solution for this issue. you can set `Sys.setlocale` this way: type `?Sys.setlocale` in your console. In the example section at the bottom there are some examples. All in all it is inuittive how to set and get locals. For example after setting to your location. Try `Sys.time()` and `Sys.Date()` and `x <- c(1,2)
month.abb[x]`. Then you can check if your system is affected or not. In this way I turned back to `German`.

Comment: I have a comment sir, First thank you so much again but I have encounter that when the format of the month in abbreviated F.I instead of "Abril" is "abr" or instead of "Diciembre" is "dic" the function will only give "NAs" I would be so thankful if you can help me out with that